# Error converting Optional<String> to Integer from TextInputDialog

Tags: java, type-conversion

In this example I have tempSocket1 and tempSocket2 but I really just want one of them. I just included both to show I tried both methods, but I keep getting an error, "the method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Optional)." I thought both of these methods were the ones used for converting a string data type to integer, but I'm not sure how the Optional part changes the whole system.

```
private void showTextInputDialog() {
        TextInputDialog changePort = new TextInputDialog("Settings");
        changePort.setHeaderText("Change Port");
        changePort.setContentText("Please enter port number to be used for establishing connection...");

        Optional<String> result = changePort.showAndWait();
        result.ifPresent(e -> {
            Integer tempSocket1 = Integer.valueOf(result);
            Integer tempSocket2 = Integer.parseInt(result);
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: If you have an `Optional<String>` and you want the `String`, you have to use `get()` to get it.  Java isn't going to do that automatically.  Note that `Optional` is a class just like any other, and it has its own methods.  There aren't any special Java language rules about `Optional`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html.

Comment: Oh, wow, I actually had no idea that Optional was its own class. I did get it to work like you said by first getting the string result and then parsing that new string to an integer, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see, `Integer.valueOf` and `Integer.parseInt` methods need an argument of type `String`, but you are passing an `Optional<String>`. So that's why the error occurred. *Optional string and string are not the same.*

Just think about this, if `Optional<String>` *were* the same as `String`, would `ArrayList<String>` be the same as `String`? Would `LinkedList<String>` be the same as `String`? What about `HashMap<String, Integer>`? Would it be both a `String` *and* an `Integer`?

The chaos that treating generic types the same as their generic type arguments would bring is destructive! Imagine calling `charAt` on an optional string! Without the implementation, no one knows what will happen...

**So yeah, *never* think that generic types are the same types as the generic type parameters.**

Answer (score 4):

To convert an Optional to an Integer, it is necessary to invoke the get() method before the conversion.

```
Optional<String> cadena = Optional.of("333");
Integer num = Integer.valueOf(cadena.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass an [`Optional<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead of a normal `String`. You need to fetch the string first with [`.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) before converting your result to an integer. Or use result.ifPresent(e ...) that will automatically unwrap the optional value and convert it to an Integer.

```
Optional<String> result = changePort.showAndWait();
result.ifPresent(e -> {
    Integer tempSocket1 = Integer.valueOf(e);
    Integer tempSocket2 = Integer.parseInt(e);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend other answers it may looks better using `map` method, and even more with lambda and method reference:

```
Optional<String> result = changePort.showAndWait();
Integer tempSocket = result.map(Integer::valueOf).orElse(8080);
```